# App starts fine with "boot",does not start when i do java -jar. What am i missing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Hello so i have a multi project set up that we have inherited and trying to dockerize. i am able to successfully run the application with spring boot cmd:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local ./gradlew :products:myapp:bootRun
```

However,when i do the following:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local myapp.jar
```

i am facing the error:

```
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.bootstrap.ProviderSpecificBootstrap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[myapp.jar:na]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[myapp.jar:na]
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
```

`My Application.java has

```
    @Import({
    EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class,
    ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthEndpointConfigImpl.class,
    EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class Application
{}
```

gradle file for this product:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {


    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: rev_spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: rev_spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-actuator', version: rev_spring_boot
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: rev_spring_boot

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: rev_junit
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: rev_mockito
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: rev_hamcrest
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: rev_spring
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

gradle file outside of this:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll { it.buildFile.exists() }) {
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: rev_spring_boot
    }
}

plugins.withId('java') {
    processResources {
        inputs.properties(['version': version])
        doLast {
            ant.propertyfile(file: new File("${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/config/application.properties")) {
                entry key: 'spring.application.version', value: version
            }
        }
    }
}

plugins.withId('org.springframework.boot') {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat') with module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${rev_spring_boot}")
        }
    }

    springBoot {
        backupSource = false
        layout = 'JAR'
    }

    bootRepackage {
        withJarTask = jar

    }
```

I am stuck at this point. tried to research the errors,but not of much help.
i am guessing the import EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class is the culprit,but wondering why when we run it as a spring boot,it's fine.

Comment: The exception appears to be complaining about the format of a JAR file, different from your application jar: `testcases-0.20-boot.jar`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo,the application jar is the testcases-0.20-boot.jar. I have updated the detail and the log.

Comment: Well, I don't see an update to the example command line, but in any case, the fact remains that the exception claims that the JAR is malformed.  I see no reason to doubt its accuracy.

Comment: I extracted the app jar file and see that the javaee-api is present,inside which the ProviderSpecificBootstrap class is present as well.The jar appears to be well formed.